# Spring Boot and Spring Data org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data

I've setup a new Spring Boot application using Spring Data. I'm trying to perform a really simple query on the database, but the error logs are reporting that there's something wrong with the query, and I can't figure out why.

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'lines line0_' at line 1
```

The Database Table is setup as follows;

### lines

BIGINT | id
VARCHAR | name
TEXT | storage_path
TINYINT(1) | active

The Line entity looks like this;

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lines")
public class Line {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name="storage_path")
    private String storagePath;

    @Column(name="active", columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1)")
    private Boolean active;
    }
```

As I'm using Spring Data, my repository looks like this;

```
@Repository
public interface LineRepository extends CrudRepository<Line, Long> {

    /**
     * Return a list of lines by their active value
     * @param active the active value
     * @return List of lines
     */
    public List<Line> getByActive(Boolean active);

}
```

All I'm trying to do it call the findAll() method on the LineRepository, but it's raising the error above.

EDIT: Below is the query being executed, I can't see anything wrong with it;

```
SELECT
        l 
    FROM
        Line l */ select
            line0_.id as id1_0_,
            line0_.active as active2_0_,
            line0_.name as name3_0_,
            line0_.storage_path as storage_4_0_ 
        from
            lines line0_
```

Comment: Do you have any other exception or error except this one liner?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that 'lines' is a reserved word in MySQL, hence why the queries where invalid.

I've changed the name of my table and it has resolved the issue.